# How can I see the model as visualized?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to do some sample code of `GAN`, here comes the generator.

I want to see the visualized model but, this is not the model.

`Model.summary()` is not the function of [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) but it is [keras](/questions/tagged/keras)?? if so how can I see visualized model??

```
g_model = generator(input_z, output_channel_dim)
g_model.summary() // AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

My function is here.

```
def generator(z, output_channel_dim, is_train=True):

    with tf.variable_scope("generator", reuse= not is_train):
        
        # First FC layer --> 8x8x1024
        fc1 = tf.layers.dense(z, 8*8*1024)
        
        # Reshape it
        fc1 = tf.reshape(fc1, (-1, 8, 8, 1024))
        
        # Leaky ReLU
        fc1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(fc1, alpha=alpha)

        
        # Transposed conv 1 --> BatchNorm --> LeakyReLU
        # 8x8x1024 --> 16x16x512
        trans_conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs = fc1,
                                  filters = 512,
                                  kernel_size = [5,5],
                                  strides = [2,2],
                                  padding = "SAME",
                                kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                name="trans_conv1")
        
        batch_trans_conv1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs = trans_conv1, training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, name="batch_trans_conv1")
       
        trans_conv1_out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_trans_conv1, alpha=alpha, name="trans_conv1_out")
        
        
        # Transposed conv 2 --> BatchNorm --> LeakyReLU
        # 16x16x512 --> 32x32x256
        trans_conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs = trans_conv1_out,
                                  filters = 256,
                                  kernel_size = [5,5],
                                  strides = [2,2],
                                  padding = "SAME",
                                kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                name="trans_conv2")
        
        batch_trans_conv2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs = trans_conv2, training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, name="batch_trans_conv2")
       
        trans_conv2_out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_trans_conv2, alpha=alpha, name="trans_conv2_out")
        
        
        # Transposed conv 3 --> BatchNorm --> LeakyReLU
        # 32x32x256 --> 64x64x128
        trans_conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs = trans_conv2_out,
                                  filters = 128,
                                  kernel_size = [5,5],
                                  strides = [2,2],
                                  padding = "SAME",
                                kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                name="trans_conv3")
        
        batch_trans_conv3 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs = trans_conv3, training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, name="batch_trans_conv3")
       
        trans_conv3_out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_trans_conv3, alpha=alpha, name="trans_conv3_out")

        
        # Transposed conv 4 --> BatchNorm --> LeakyReLU
        # 64x64x128 --> 128x128x64
        trans_conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs = trans_conv3_out,
                                  filters = 64,
                                  kernel_size = [5,5],
                                  strides = [2,2],
                                  padding = "SAME",
                                kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                name="trans_conv4")
        
        batch_trans_conv4 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(inputs = trans_conv4, training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, name="batch_trans_conv4")
       
        trans_conv4_out = tf.nn.leaky_relu(batch_trans_conv4, alpha=alpha, name="trans_conv4_out")

        
        # Transposed conv 5 --> tanh
        # 128x128x64 --> 128x128x3
        logits = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(inputs = trans_conv4_out,
                                  filters = 3,
                                  kernel_size = [5,5],
                                  strides = [1,1],
                                  padding = "SAME",
                                kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                name="logits")
         
        out = tf.tanh(logits, name="out")
        
        return out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution (or an idea) is to wrap your [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow) operation into the [Lambda layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda) and use it to build the [keras](/questions/tagged/keras) model. Something like

```
# add a x -> x^2 layer
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x ** 2))
```

But it's not the general solution (AFAIK), and also while it is possible to use **Variables** with **Lambda** layers, **this practice is discouraged** as it can easily **lead to bugs**. And that exactly what we've encountered when trying to wrap your `generator` function into the **Lambda** layer. Here what we've tried and received:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.__version__ # 2.5

def generator(z, output_channel_dim=10, is_train=True, alpha = 0.1):
    with tf.compat.v1.variable_scope("generator", reuse=tf.compat.v1.AUTO_REUSE):
        # First FC layer --> 8x8x1024
        fc1 = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(z, 8*8*1024)
    ......
    ......
```

```
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda

generator(tf.ones((1, 8, 8, 1)), is_train=True).shape
TensorShape([64, 128, 128, 3])
```

**Wrapping to the Lambda layer**

For that, we received such a warning, a potential bug.

```
x = keras.Input(shape=(8, 8, 1))
y = Lambda(generator)(x)
```

```
WARNING:tensorflow:
The following Variables were used a Lambda layer's call (lambda_1), but
are not present in its tracked objects:
  <tf.Variable 'generator/dense/kernel:0' shape=(1, 65536) dtype=float32>
  <tf.Variable 'generator/dense/bias:0' shape=(65536,) dtype=float32>
  <tf.Variable 'generator/trans_conv1/kernel:0' shape=(5, 5, 512, 1024) dtype=float32>
  <tf.Variable 'generator/trans_conv1/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>
.....
.....
```

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model 
model = Model(inputs=x, outputs=y)
model.summary()

Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_3 (InputLayer)         [(None, 8, 8, 1)]         0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_2 (Lambda)            (None, 128, 128, 3)       0         
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

`tf.Variables` are not present in the tracked objects.

Comment: THank you it looks like useful way. I am familliar with Keras but not tensorflow itself. I will try this way.